# Excel VBA Sort when Inputting Data, Updated in All Other Sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, excel-2010

I am new to VBA Excel.

I wanna create a database for each month, with 1 'Main Sheet' for the list of names, and the list on 'Main Sheet' will sort automatically as a row when I entered data along with the update of the other sheet.

I found this code, and it's only updated/sorting in the sheet entered (let's say the 'Main Sheet'). Is that possible if the entered data and sorting updated automatically in all other sheets?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
    
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Range("A2:BN2" & lastRow).Sort key1:=Range("A2:A" & lastRow), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
    
    End If
End Sub
```

I tried referencing/paste the link to the name for each month (start from A2), but I have no idea to keep the column beside A2 (B2, C2, etc) sticking with the A2 as a full row.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look at this part of your code for ideas how to solve your problem.

```
Range("A2:BN2" & lastRow).Sort Key1:=Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
```

The instruction is to sort `Range("A2:BN2" & lastRow)` on *Key1*. The range to sort starts at A2 and ends with the last used row in column BN. All columns of all rows are included, as they should. But *lastRow* was determined in column 1, which is column A. We hope that all columns have the same length. Observe that we don't know on which tab the range is located. By default, if no sheet is specified, Excel will presume the ActiveSheet. This is borne out by the fact that the code is located in a worksheet event procedure. Of course, this code is linked to the sheet on whose code module it is placed. It won't run when another sheet is active.

However, the syntax for specifying a range for a particular sheet would look like this.

```
With Worksheets("MySheet")
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set MyRange = .Range("A2:BN2" & lastRow)
End With
```

Please observe all the leading periods, each of which links the statement it precedes to the worksheet specified in the *With* statement. Imagine a loop in which the sheet name is changed on each turn, thereby defining the same range on a different sheet on each instance.

The *Key* argument of the *Sort* method specified the column on which to sort. It's called "Key" instead of "Column" because there are sheet columns and range columns. In your case the sheet rows are different from your range rows because your range starts in row 2 but the range columns are identical with the sheet columns. Anyway, `Key1:=Range("A2:A" & lastRow)` isn't a very good pointer to the column you want to sort on. 1 single cell would suffice, like  `Key1:=Range("A2")` - or `Key1:=Cells(2, 1)` as I would prefer.

As you see, this part is a lot simpler. The only important point to observe is that the cell specifying the *Key* must be within the range to be sorted. This also means that you can't specify a *Key* on the ActiveSheet for a sort range on another tab. When you construct your loop, therefore, you will need to take a cell from the properly defined sort range as *Key*.